# Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I've been trying to assign a function pointer (of a class) to a member function (of another class) like this:

```
--- Game.h ---
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "Screen.h"

class Game
{
private:
    void (*HandleCurrentScreen)();

public:
    void SetScreen(const Screen& newScreen);
};

#endif



--- Game.cpp ---
#include "Game.h"
#include "Screen.h"

void Game::SetScreen(const Screen& newScreen)
{
    HandleCurrentScreen = newScreen.Handle;    //Produces the error
}



--- Screen.h ---
#ifndef SCREEN_H
#define SCREEN_H

class Screen
{
public:
    void Handle();
};

#endif



--- Screen.cpp ---
#include "Screen.h"

void Screen::Handle()
{
    ...
}
```

I get this error:

> error C3867: 'Screen::Handle': function call missing argument list; use '&Screen::Handle' to create a pointer to member

It seems to work fine if `HandleCurrentScreen` points to a function that is also defined in the Game class. I've been looking for other people with this problem, but none seem to have it in cases like this.

A solution that might work is something like this:

```
Screen* p_currentScreen;

void Game::SetScreen(const Screen& newScreen)
{
    p_currentScreen = &newScreen;
}
```

and then instead of calling `HandleCurrentScreen` I can call `p_currentScreen->Handle()`, but this seems slightly less efficient to me.

What can I do to fix this? Should I just use a pointer to a class instead of a function pointer?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: C++ is not a late-binding language. It definitely wasn't designed for you to be able to overwrite the vtable at run-time. Your second method is how it should be done.

Comment: @aruisdante Either I don't understand the code or I don't understand your comment. There is no vtable here.

Comment: Maybe I read the code/description wrong, but it looked like the OP was trying to override what a class's method resolves to at runtime via assignment. Similar to how you could in, say, python, do ``instance.FUNCTION_NAME = NEW_FUNCTION`` where ``FUNCTION_NAME`` is a class method and ``NEW_FUNCTION`` is a callable, and now any time any other portion of the code called ``instance.FUNCTION_NAME()`` they would actually be calling ``NEW_FUNCTION``.

Comment: @didierc That's only half the story as type of `HandleCurrentScreen` is wrong for member function pointer.

Comment: Use `std::bind` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: @didierc How does that help?

Comment: `HandleCurrentScreen` should be `void (Screen::*HandleCurrentScreen)()`, but it will do you little good as you still need a `Screen` instance (or derivation therein) to wire to it at invoke time. Your *intent* isn't entirely clear (why you feel you need a pointer-to-member in the first place, as opposed to your second option, which seems all you need).

Comment: @NeilKirk, it's a hint. If you already know the template, then you'll figure it out. Otherwise, there's a couple of answers below using it (including mine). Thank you for asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error tells you what to do:

```
Screen::Handle': function call missing argument list; use '&Screen::Handle
```

You should write it as:

```
void Game::SetScreen(const Screen& newScreen)
{
    HandleCurrentScreen = &Screen::Handle;
}
```

It will work only in case `newScreen::handle` is a static function. But in that case you could initialize it at compile time. Otherwise `HandleCurrentScreen` should be a pointer to a member function (PTMF) declared as:

```
void (Screen::*HandleCurrentScreen)();
```

Now, in order to call the function from a PTMF you need a function object as well. That makes your second solution better.

Another option is std::bind:

```
class Game
{
private:
    std::function<void()> HandleCurrentScreen;

public:
    void SetScreen(const Screen& newScreen) {
        HandleCurrentScreen = std::bind(&Screen::Handle, &newScreen);
    }
};
```

Comment: Of course, ``std::bind`` only exists in C++11. If you're on an earlier compiler, you'll have to use ``boost::bind``, which is where ``std::bind`` got its inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

`std::bind` is made to solve that sort of problem:

```
// --- Game.h ---
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "Screen.h"
#include <functional>

class Game {
private:
    std::function<void ()> HandleCurrentScreen;
public:
    void SetScreen(const Screen& newScreen);
};

#endif


 // -- Game.cc --

#include "Game.h"
#include "Screen.h"

void Game::SetScreen(const Screen& newScreen){
   HandleCurrentScreen = std::bind( &Screen::Handle, newScreen);
}
```

However, since your `Game` class only needs a function, it's probably better design to leave the `Screen` class completely out of `Game` definition, and pass it the function directly:

```
#include <functional>

class Game {
public:
    typedef std::function<void ()> ScreenHandler;
private:
    ScreenHandler HandleCurrentScreen;
public:
    void SetHandle(const ScreenHandler &handle);
};

#endif

 // -- Game.cc --

#include "Game.h"

void Game::SetHandle(const ScreenHandler &handle){
   HandleCurrentScreen = handle;
}
```

That way you have the choice of constructing that handler the way you see fit, without involving `Game`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make whatever function that is static.